# Radio button values not getting clear and alert messages issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, radio-button

I am building a Quiz App. I am facing issue with checkAns() function. The problem i am facing is after giving a correct/incorrect ans my app is getting stuck with the alert msgs "choose atleast one option" even though i have selected an option. I have to click multiple times on the ok button of the alert msg "choose atleast one option" in order for the next question to be appear. I have tried debugging it but i am unable to find the problem.

```js
const quizData = [{ question: 'How old are you?', a: '10', b: '20', c: '23', d: '50', correctAns: 'c', count: 0 }, { question: 'WWW stands for?', a: 'World Wide Web', b: 'Web Wide World', c: 'Worldy Wide web', d: 'none of the above', correctAns: 'a', count: 0 }, { question: 'Adult age in india?', a: '20', b: '18', c: '17', d: '50', correctAns: 'b', count: 0 }, { question: 'Capital of India?', a: 'Bhopal', b: 'Mumbai', c: 'Kolkata', d: 'New Delhi', correctAns: 'd', count: 0 }, { question: 'Capital of MP?', a: 'Bhopal', b: 'Burhanpur', c: 'Indore', d: 'Guna', correctAns: 'a', count: 0 } ];

const question = document.getElementById('question')
const optionA = document.getElementById('a_text')
const optionB = document.getElementById('b_text')
const optionC = document.getElementById('c_text')
const optionD = document.getElementById('d_text')
const input = document.querySelectorAll('input')
const btnSubmit = document.getElementById('submit')
const radioBtnValue = document.getElementsByName('answer')
let index;
function getRandomQuestion() {
  return (Math.floor(Math.random() * quizData.length))
}
function radioBtn() {
  let element;
  radioBtnValue.forEach((el) => {
    if (el.checked) {
      element = el.id
      return;
    }
    return;
  })
  return element
}
function clearRadioBtnValues() {
  radioBtnValue.forEach((el) => {
    el.checked = false
  })
  return
}
function checkAns(value, index) {
  if (value === quizData[index].correctAns) {
    alert('correct ans')
    clearRadioBtnValues()
    startQuiz()
  } else if (value === undefined) {
    alert('choose atleast one option')
  } else {
    alert('incorrect ans')
    clearRadioBtnValues()
    startQuiz()
  }
}
function startQuiz() {
  index = getRandomQuestion()
  if (quizData[index].count === 0) {
    question.innerHTML = quizData[index].question
    optionA.innerHTML = quizData[index].a
    optionB.innerHTML = quizData[index].b
    optionC.innerHTML = quizData[index].c
    optionD.innerHTML = quizData[index].d
    quizData[index].count++
      btnSubmit.addEventListener('click', function() {
        let radioBtnValue = radioBtn()
        checkAns(radioBtnValue, index)
      })
  }
}
window.onload = startQuiz
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;400;600&display=swap");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #b8c6db;
  background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #b8c6db 0%, #f5f7fa 100%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.quiz-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.quiz-header {
  padding: 4rem;
}

h2 {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

ul li label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  background-color: #8e44ad;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.3rem;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #732d91;
}

button:focus {
  background-color: #5e3370;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Quiz App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="quiz-container" id="quiz">
    <div class="quiz-header">
      <h2 id="question">Question text</h2>
      <ul id="main-ul">
        <li>
          <input type="radio" id="a" name="answer" class="answer" />
          <label id="a_text" for="a"></label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" id="b" name="answer" class="answer" />
          <label id="b_text" for="b"></label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" id="c" name="answer" class="answer" />
          <label id="c_text" for="c"></label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" id="d" name="answer" class="answer" />
          <label id="d_text" for="d"></label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please consider removing unrelevant code when you ask a question. For example you don't need to put all the quizData Adding just one is enough for everyone to understand whats going on. Also styling is unnecessary here. Not all of the HTML is relevant for this question. Focusing on the important part will help you to get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You kept adding the eventlistener to the button every time you called the startQuiz

So `let radioBtnValue = radioBtn(); checkAns(radioBtnValue, index)` would be called again and again after the first startsQuiz

Here is a much simpler version. I kept your HTML but renamed the button since you should never use "submit" as ID or NAME in case you ever are inside a form you want to submit using script.

```js
const quizData = [{ question: 'How old are you?', a: '10', b: '20', c: '23', d: '50', correctAns: 'c', count: 0 }, { question: 'WWW stands for?', a: 'World Wide Web', b: 'Web Wide World', c: 'Worldy Wide web', d: 'none of the above', correctAns: 'a', count: 0 }, { question: 'Adult age in india?', a: '20', b: '18', c: '17', d: '50', correctAns: 'b', count: 0 }, { question: 'Capital of India?', a: 'Bhopal', b: 'Mumbai', c: 'Kolkata', d: 'New Delhi', correctAns: 'd', count: 0 }, { question: 'Capital of MP?', a: 'Bhopal', b: 'Burhanpur', c: 'Indore', d: 'Guna', correctAns: 'a', count: 0 } ] 

function getRandomQuestion() {
  return (Math.floor(Math.random() * quizData.length))
}

function checkAns(index) {
  const rad = document.querySelector("#main-ul [type=radio]:checked"); // only find checked radio
  const value = rad ? rad.id : ""; // if none checked, set empty value

  if (!value) {
    alert('choose at least one option')
    return; // leave the function
  }
  const res = value === quizData[index].correctAns ? 'correct ans' : 'incorrect ans'; // this is called a ternary
  alert(res);
  [...document.querySelectorAll("#main-ul [type=radio]")].forEach(el => el.checked = false);
  
  quizData.splice(index, 1); // remove question
  
  startQuiz();
}

let index; // global var.
function startQuiz() {
  if (quizData.length===0) {
    document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = "No more questions";
    document.getElementById("main-ul").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("subbut").style.display="none";
    return;
  }
  index = getRandomQuestion();
  document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = quizData[index].question;
  // DRY, don't repeat yourself
  ["a","b","c","d"].forEach(letter => document.getElementById(letter+'_text').innerHTML = quizData[index][letter])
}
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when the page loads
  document.getElementById('subbut').addEventListener('click', function() {
    checkAns(index);
  })
  startQuiz();
})
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;400;600&display=swap");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #b8c6db;
  background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #b8c6db 0%, #f5f7fa 100%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.quiz-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.quiz-header {
  padding: 4rem;
}

h2 {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

ul li label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  background-color: #8e44ad;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.3rem;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #732d91;
}

button:focus {
  background-color: #5e3370;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Quiz App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="quiz-container" id="quiz">
    <div class="quiz-header">
      <h2 id="question">Question text</h2>
      <ul id="main-ul">
        <li>
          <input type="radio" id="a" name="answer" class="answer" />
          <label id="a_text" for="a"></label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" id="b" name="answer" class="answer" />
          <label id="b_text" for="b"></label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" id="c" name="answer" class="answer" />
          <label id="c_text" for="c"></label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" id="d" name="answer" class="answer" />
          <label id="d_text" for="d"></label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <button id="subbut">Submit</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the above code you wrote has removed my multiple listeners issue. but there is one bug which i have observed with the above code. whenever a same question appears twice i.e the random function generates the same index twice in a row and i have selected the correct option both the times. in the second time i m getting the alert message incorrect ans even though i have selected the correct one.

Comment: yeah its fine now. thanx. i got the point that i m adding event listeners again again. so i have made changes in my old code. apart from that my logic of getting the radio btn values and clearing them was too complex. i will use your code as reference. also i m begginner to js so do you have any advice for me how can i improve myself.

Comment: Actually I do not. I have been writing JS since 1995 or so... Answer a lot of questions here helps because that forces you to figure things out

Comment: ohk i will be making more mini projects that will help. and if i get stuck somewhere SO is there always.

Answer (score 0):

If you submit the answer and reassign new ones, your check Answer function is assigning the on-click-event again.

Using element.addEventListener() you can add as many events to a single node as you want. Using element.onclick = function(){} or element.setAttribute("onclick", "string..."); you can assign just one and overwrite it every time.

You can solve this, if you split the assign-functions methods from checking the result and assigning a new question.

Comment: Just writing code for others without any kind of comment or explaination is no help to understand whats wrong and how to avoid this in the future. Even tho, your solution might work from what i can see, but there is no explanation why this and not that. You mention the addEventListener issue, but rewrote half of the code. The author seems not to be very experienced with JS, so your complex changes to his script may throw up new questions. This is no help in my opinion and our answers are only a few seconds apart from each other.